# Poweredge 750 cannot startup after power failure

Tags: dell-poweredge, bios

After a recent power failure my poweredge 750 powers on but just sits on the Dell A06 bios loading screen.  I tried resetting the bios' memory by removing the battery and restarting after 15min to no avail.  Is there any approach to take to try to recover from this "stuck" state?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any approach to take to try to recover from this "stuck" state?

Yeah, it's called troubleshooting.

Start by removing hardware one piece at a time until you identify the culprit. Try each DIMM individually, one PSU at a time if you have redundant ones, disconnect the HDD backplane, remove the RAID controller, etc.

Hopefully, removing one of these things will cause the server to boot and you'll know what went bad. If not, it could be a damaged motherboard or CPU.